# Using message box output as variables as input to VBA code

Tags: vba, variables, messagebox

The below code doesn't work on the 4th line. If some one can help.
I would like to use the information from the input box to feed in to the VBA code.
if the msg box says b25, I would want it copy the data from b25 and paste it in another sheet as shown below.

Thanks

```
Sub MsgBoxYesNoCancel()

    input_Cells = InputBox("Input column")
    MsgBox "Want to Continue?", vbYesNoCancel
    input_Celli = InputBox("Input row number")

    ActiveSheet.Range("'input_Cells' & 'input_Celli'").Copy
    Worksheets("ACV").Activate
    Range("G36").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues  

End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the quotes... `ActiveSheet.Range(input_Cells & input_Celli).Copy`... but you really sure use `Application.InputBox` to select a range instead of the approach you are taking.

Answer (score 0):

This is the implementation of what @BigBen suggested. You can either enter a cell reference or simply click on a cell or range. Note that an error will occur if the user clicks the Cancel button and the code allows a gracious exit from the macro in that case.

```
Sub CopyToG36()

    Dim Source      As Variant          ' range to copy from

    On Error Resume Next
    Set Source = Application.InputBox("Select the source data", "Transfer data", Type:=8)
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        Source.Copy Destination:=Cells(36, "G")
    End If
End Sub
```

The logical extension of the above thought is to have no InputBox at all. You can simply select what you want to copy and run the macro. For that action a single line of code is sufficient. Try it.

```
Sub CopyToG36_2()
    Selection.Copy Destination:=Cells(36, "G")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the code. It's really help full.I need to copy and transfer it to another worksheet.What should I put instead of this: Selection.Copy Destination:=Cells(36, "G")

Comment: I added the following code and didn't work Source.Copy.Activate.Sheets("5").Select.Cells(36, "G").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: `Selection.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(36, "G")`. Please remember that you don't need to hold a person's hand to talk to him, and you don't need to Select or Activate a tab, range or cell in order to read from or write to it.